# Может ли сравнение строк быть быстрее сравнения чисел?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Прочитал вот [эту](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-reasons-to-explicitly-convert-sql-server-data-types/) статью и был озадачен советом #9: Cast for quicker search.

Пишут, что вот этот запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.EmployeeSick
WHERE CAST(SickLeaveHours AS char(3)) <> 0
```

может отрабатывать быстрее, чем запрос без каста. Не всегда, но может. `SickLeaveHours` имеет тип `int`.

Как такое может быть? Ведь здравый смысл подсказывает, что на каст будет тратиться время.

Comment: Лучше спросить у автора статьи в каких случаях он это получил. Как минимум такая запись может приводить к изменению плана выполнения. Автор статьи мог бы и привести пару планов для таких случаев. Возможно это бы пролило свет. И кстати я тут все равно не вижу сравнения строк. Я например не знаю приведет ли он 0 к строке для сравнения или приведет строку опять к числу

Comment: @Mike - верное замечание. У меня тоже подспудно вертелась мысль, как будет сравниваться `char(n)` с `int`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: думаю, все же int будет приведен к строке. По логике вещей: каждое число можно представить в виде строки, но не каждую строку можно представить числом

Comment: Согласно документации MS https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql char(n) будет преобразован в int и лишь потом будет произведено сравнение.

Comment: Если у вас по рукой есть SQL Server и база, где этот эффект наблюдается, вы можете просто сравнить план выполнения. Management Studio показывает очень подробный план, с указанием количества данные, читаемых на каждом этапе.

Comment: Видимо действительно попытка подавить возможное использование индекса (если оптимизатор ошибся в том, что его надо использовать). Того же можно добиться с помощью хинта на таблицу `SELECT * FROM HumanResources.EmployeeSick WITH (FORCESCAN) WHERE ...`, не применяя дополнительный каст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как такое может быть?

Могу предположить, что данный трюк может работать, из-за особенностей использования индекса. Если запрос должен обработать больше половины записей таблицы, то полный перебор эффективнее индексного чтения.

В Firebord того же эффекта добиваются добавлением нуля: `WHERE SickLeaveHours+0 <> 0`

> на каст будет тратиться время.

Время на такой cast исчезающе мало по сравнению со временем чтения с диска.

Уменьшение I/O за счет отсутствия необходимости читать индекс (в дополнение к данным) перекроет расход на cast.

Comment: Понятно. Теперь, по крайней мере, ясно, в каком направлении гуглить.

Comment: Подожду ещё пару дней других ответов (вдруг кто вспомнит секретную фичу SqlServer), потом приму ответ.

Comment: Меня лично напрягло условие `<> 0`. Поэтому я в комментариях и сказал размытую фразу "может изменится план выполнения". Я не сталкивался с ситуациями, когда СУБД решала бы использовать индекс для поиска по "НЕ равно". Потому что обходить все дерево индекса кроме одного листа довольно утомительное занятие. Хотя наверное если статистика ей подскажет, что 0 - это очень весомая часть, может и пойти. Т.е. по моим представлениям индекс тут и так использоваться вроде как не должен и применять разные трюки для его отключения вроде как ни к чему

Comment: _"Если запрос должен обработать больше половины записей таблицы..."_ - не обязательно половины, кстати, просто больше какого-то количества записей

Comment: @Mike, _"Я не сталкивался с ситуациями, когда СУБД решала бы использовать индекс для поиска по "НЕ равно" ... Хотя наверное если статистика ей подскажет"_ - да, вполне, условие `<>0` может задействовать не уникальный индекс.

Answer (score 4):

Это подавление использования индекса по полю SickLeaveHours. Предположим, что есть некий индекс:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_EmployeeSick_SickLeaveHours ON [HumanResources].[EmployeeSick]
(
    SickLeaveHours ASC
)
```

Тогда возможен выбор оптимизатором такого плана запроса:

1. Сканирование индекса idx_EmployeeSick_SickLeaveHours (не поиск из-за операции `<>`)
2. KeyLookup-ы по полученным записям из кластерного индекса/таблицы, так как у нас запрос
   `SELECT *`.

В случае, если по первому пункту вернется достаточно много записей, вторая операция будет очень дорогой по чтениям, но оптимизатор может ошибиться с оценкой количества записей по ряду причин (устаревшая либо сэмплированная статистика, например) и выбрать план с лукапами вместо сканирования кластерного индекса/таблицы.

При использовании предиката `CAST(SickLeaveHours AS char(3)) <> 0` из-за преобразований по столбцу `SickLeaveHours`, а их там будет на самом деле два - явное к `char(3)`, а затем неявное к `int`, индекс по полю `SickLeaveHours` использоваться не может, поэтому будет построен план со сканированием кластерного индекса и таким предикатом:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,CONVERT(char(3), HumanResources.EmployeeSick.[SickLeaveHours],0),0)<>(0)
```

Как справедливо заметили в комментариях, такого же результата можно добиться хинтами, явно указав какой индекс использовать.